# Wireless-AC 9560 not working after reboot but work if shutdown and start

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi, 20.10

I had Laptop Dell Inspiron 7786 Ubuntu 5.8.0-25.26-generic

Ubuntu's main system without Dual Booting and etc.
Also, I try several versions of Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 20.10 and Fedora 32.

After turn down and start the system WiFi work normally. Kernel boot log:

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 18:1d:ea:7e:f4:4b
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

But if I reboot the system I got "No WiFi Adapter available"
Kernel boot log (after reboot):

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x57EBE7FA | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3DEFF6EE | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAA22218C | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31101204 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7B5E8EE9 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48382987 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x226c
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

I try many cases from the internet system but got no effect.

Comment: What is `5.8.14` in your question? Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: "What is 5.8.14 in your question? " it's a response from cat /proc/version_signature
"Is it a dual boot with Windows?" - no just Ubuntu as the main system

Comment: It's not duplicate because i don't have dual-booting!!!

Comment: OK. No problem. Then it must be a kernel  bug.

Comment: There is a workaround. I haven't been able to find a proper fix, but you can use this workaround for now. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311300/1175625)