# Ubuntu 20.10 slow wifi and frequent disconnection

Tags: networking, internet, iwlwifi, 20.10

I was using ubuntu 20.04 LTS recently. Upgraded to 20.10 trying to fix the issue but issue remains.

I was using LAN cable to connect to the internet, it sometimes shows as 100mbps Lan connection and i unplug the cable and plug it back. It shows up as 1000mbps and I get my 300Mbps up/dw speed back on LAN. it was a bit  of inconvenience, but I was fine with it.

Today I had to ditch my LAN cable and I found out that Wi-Fi is terrible on Ubuntu.

I found few answers after googling

- power saving mode from 3 to 2 - didn't work
- `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

but this bug has been patched already. Even if i try that command it says package doesn't exist so not removed

-`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` :
`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1`. this also didn't work so I undo what I did.

- changing selected drivers from under additional drivers. but I don't have wifi drivers under it. I only have my nvidia graphics under it. So i am guessing its not using additional drivers for my network card.
- Tried bootable usb and booted into manjaro, ubuntu 20.10, elementary 5.1 and all face the same issue. awful speeds on wifi and frequent disconnection.

I barely get 30Mbps in ubuntu but if boot into windows i get full 300Mbps. Sometimes I do get 80-90Mbps but never full speed. no internet at boot and i have to wait few minutes for the internet to work. I get full 300Mbps on LAN. ALl my other connected devices get full speed as well. only issue with my laptop when I am using ubuntu and wifi 5ghz network.

My laptop model gf63 thin 9SC core i5 9th gen nvidia 1650

I have spent whole day today on this issue. Might have to switch back to LAN only. Which is fine when I am at home but not so good when I am on move.

output of uname -r

```
5.8.0-40-generic
```

my network card details

```
*-network
     description: Wireless interface
     product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
     logical name: wlo1
     version: 10
     serial: 40:74:e0:a5:f3:ac
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic firmware=46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.0.152 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
     resources: irq:16 memory:a4414000-a4417fff

 *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
        logical name: enp3s0
        version: 15
        serial: 00:d8:61:85:eb:b9
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
        resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

output of sudo dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    3.202246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.219912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    3.219914] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    3.219915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    3.219916] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    3.219917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    3.219918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    3.219919] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    3.219920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    3.219921] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    3.219922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    3.219923] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    3.219924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    3.219925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    3.219926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    3.219927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    3.219928] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    3.219931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.219932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.220181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.227032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.333438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    3.382169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 40:74:e0:a5:f3:ac
[    3.449327] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.640194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   46.671456] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 12 is active on fifo 0 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [0, 32] HW [0, 32] FH TRB=0x0c000c00f
[   46.671618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   46.671988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   46.671996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[   46.672002] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[   46.672008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[   46.672014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002EF4 | trm_hw_status0
[   46.672020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   46.672025] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0048865E | branchlink2
[   46.672030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00478C5A | interruptlink1
[   46.672035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B97C | interruptlink2
[   46.672041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001ADA2 | data1
[   46.672046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF000000 | data2
[   46.672051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
[   46.672056] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x540034D0 | beacon time
[   46.672061] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6FFAFB30 | tsf low
[   46.672067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   46.672071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   46.672077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x026E1F9D | time gp2
[   46.672082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   46.672087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
[   46.672092] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | uCode version minor
[   46.672097] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
[   46.672103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89008 | board version
[   46.672108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A0F001C | hcmd
[   46.672113] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8012200F | isr0
[   46.672118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   46.672123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
[   46.672128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x404139CC | isr3
[   46.672133] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   46.672138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00AA011D | last cmd Id
[   46.672143] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001ADA2 | wait_event
[   46.672148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004A88 | l2p_control
[   46.672153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
[   46.672158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   46.672163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000EF | l2p_addr_match
[   46.672168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   46.672173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02052033 | timestamp
[   46.672179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000E8B8 | flow_handler
[   46.672328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   46.672334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[   46.672339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   46.672345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   46.672350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BAA | umac branchlink2
[   46.672355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink1
[   46.672360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink2
[   46.672365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   46.672370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac data2
[   46.672375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   46.672380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
[   46.672385] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | umac minor
[   46.672390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x026E1F89 | frame pointer
[   46.672395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
[   46.672400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00AB0118 | last host cmd
[   46.672406] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   46.672427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   46.672439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x852D3FD3 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   46.672451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   46.672464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FBC0807 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   46.672476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   46.672488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCB0B18C1 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   46.672500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAD14EEFB | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   46.672513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB3D2BAC5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   46.672525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE28D0428 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   46.672537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   46.672551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   46.672566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   46.672611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   46.672626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[   58.959508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 12 is active on fifo 0 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [32, 50] HW [32, 50] FH TRB=0x0c000c02f
[   58.959690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   58.960052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   58.960057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[   58.960060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[   58.960065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[   58.960069] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00802EF4 | trm_hw_status0
[   58.960072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   58.960075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0048865E | branchlink2
[   58.960078] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00478C5A | interruptlink1
[   58.960081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00032BEE | interruptlink2
[   58.960084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B20E | data1
[   58.960087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF000000 | data2
[   58.960090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
[   58.960093] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x190035C4 | beacon time
[   58.960095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x70B67A3D | tsf low
[   58.960098] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   58.960101] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   58.960104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009CE2AF | time gp2
[   58.960107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   58.960110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
[   58.960113] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | uCode version minor
[   58.960116] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
[   58.960119] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89008 | board version
[   58.960122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0C20001C | hcmd
[   58.960125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022003 | isr0
[   58.960128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   58.960131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
[   58.960134] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0041F4CD | isr3
[   58.960137] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   58.960140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0BC4001C | last cmd Id
[   58.960143] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B20E | wait_event
[   58.960146] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[   58.960149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
[   58.960152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[   58.960155] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[   58.960158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   58.960160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02052033 | timestamp
[   58.960163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C87C | flow_handler
[   58.960310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   58.960313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[   58.960317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   58.960320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   58.960323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BAA | umac branchlink2
[   58.960326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink1
[   58.960329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink2
[   58.960332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   58.960335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac data2
[   58.960338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   58.960340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
[   58.960343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | umac minor
[   58.960346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009CE29C | frame pointer
[   58.960349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
[   58.960352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0068019C | last host cmd
[   58.960355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   58.960374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   58.960385] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x852D3FD3 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   58.960394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   58.960404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FBC0807 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   58.960414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   58.960424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCB0B18C1 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   58.960433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAD14EEFB | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   58.960443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB3D2BAC5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   58.960453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE28D0428 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   58.960462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   58.960474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   58.960486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   58.960528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   58.960541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[   80.719463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 12 is active on fifo 0 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [55, 73] HW [55, 73] FH TRB=0x0c000c046
[   80.719567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   80.719662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 13 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [4, 11] HW [4, 11] FH TRB=0x0c020d00a
[   80.719983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   80.719985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[   80.719987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[   80.719989] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[   80.719991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00802EF4 | trm_hw_status0
[   80.719992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   80.719994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0048865E | branchlink2
[   80.719995] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00478C5A | interruptlink1
[   80.719997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0048769C | interruptlink2
[   80.719998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B20E | data1
[   80.720000] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF000000 | data2
[   80.720001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
[   80.720002] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x30010007 | beacon time
[   80.720004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x72027FF8 | tsf low
[   80.720005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   80.720007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   80.720008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x012D5979 | time gp2
[   80.720010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   80.720011] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
[   80.720013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | uCode version minor
[   80.720014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
[   80.720016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89008 | board version
[   80.720017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0D04001C | hcmd
[   80.720018] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022007 | isr0
[   80.720020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   80.720021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
[   80.720023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004160CD | isr3
[   80.720024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   80.720026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0BE5001C | last cmd Id
[   80.720027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B20E | wait_event
[   80.720028] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A04B | l2p_control
[   80.720029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
[   80.720030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | l2p_mhvalid
[   80.720032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[   80.720033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   80.720034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02052033 | timestamp
[   80.720036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000008EC | flow_handler
[   80.720181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   80.720183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[   80.720185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   80.720186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   80.720188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BAA | umac branchlink2
[   80.720189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink1
[   80.720190] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac interruptlink2
[   80.720192] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   80.720193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084448 | umac data2
[   80.720195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   80.720196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
[   80.720198] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8902351F | umac minor
[   80.720199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x012D5967 | frame pointer
[   80.720200] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
[   80.720202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0079019C | last host cmd
[   80.720203] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   80.720221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   80.720229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x852D3FD3 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   80.720237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   80.720258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FBC0807 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   80.720268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   80.720276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCB0B18C1 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   80.720285] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAD14EEFB | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   80.720293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB3D2BAC5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   80.720301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE28D0428 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   80.720310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   80.720320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   80.720331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   80.720372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   80.720381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[  190.250408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[  190.250409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[  190.250410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[  190.250411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[  190.250411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[  190.250412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[  190.250413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[  190.250414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[  190.250414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[  190.250415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[  190.250416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[  190.250416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[  190.250417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[  190.250418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[  190.250419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[  190.250419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[  190.250422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  190.250423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[  190.250682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  190.250694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[  190.266425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
[  190.316637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 40:74:e0:a5:f3:ac
[  190.384999] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[  190.395088] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Well this line is something to look at: `[   46.671618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.`. According to Intel, when you see this message it means the wireless card's firmware crashed. Have you checked to make sure you're on the latest firmware from the vendor?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I will look into this. Thank you. I am a newbei when it comes to such issue. till now i have been able to fix most issues using google. This is the first time something has caused to much headache. I did download drivers from intel website and placed them in the suggested folder.  i found on this suggestion searching on google. I think best to do clean install and then see if i get this error or not.

Comment: @Matigo So i figured out the solution. tried few other things , installed ubuntu budgie this time, fresh installation. Googled what you suggested, tried few things. Nothing worked.  nvidia icon was showing at the top, i switched to uisng intel power saving mode and it fixed my issue. just to be sure switched back to nvidia performance mode and issue returned. switched back to intel power saving mode and wifi speed returned. don't know why nvidia usage is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I couldn't find a better way to fix this. I hope this doesn't affect my work.

After 2 days of searching I was not able to find any solution. So i finally though let's try changing some settings. I was seeing nvidia icon in the status bar which I never saw before. I came back to Ubuntu after a year or more. So this icon was new to me. So I tapped on that, performance mode was selected, it gave me the option to select intel power save mode. I selected that and my Wi-Fi issue was fixed.
I tried changing Nvidia drivers from additional drivers tab but all of them had the same issue. In the end I selected Nvidia open source drivers, no proprietary drivers. That fixed my issue as well. But Nvidia icon is no longer visible in my status bar. So I am not sure if the Nvidia card is working properly or not.
[Nvidia Open source driver selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhCT6.png)